# Render a hyperlink in a email template

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to render a hyperlink in an email template which will be sent to the user and if the user clicks on that link it will direct to a unique url. I have given the coding below,

```
email.AddMailmerge("RequestUrl", "<a href=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DomainName") & "/Requests/Requests.aspx?Company_ID=" & objCompany.IDHashed & ">Feedback Requests</a>")
```

My problem is the link doesnt resolve correctly and take me to the right url. What am I doing wrong?

It resolves as:

C:\Users\Test\Desktop\localhost/Requests/Requests.aspx?Company_ID=KirprZ17bg5u5Qf1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you Appsetting contains http:// so instead of just

```
localhost
```

it needs to be

```
http://localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to format your `href` with quotes. Instead of relying on your app.config's value, which is return the `C:\` value, use the .NET methods to get the current domain/URL.

```
Dim target As String = _
     String.Format("<a href='{0}/Requests/Requests.aspx?Company_ID={1}'>Feedback Requests</a>",_
                    Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),_
                    objCompany.IDHashed)
```

Comment: What's the value of your `DomainName` then?

Comment: localhost. we have two sites for testing and thats why we have used appsettings

Comment: Good stuff. Use the .NET methods to determine the URL that you're running under, and you won't need that anymore.

Comment: Its not in the code behind. I have used a class called EmailMerge

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strRequestLink As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DomainName") & "/Requests/Requests.aspx?Company_ID=" & Me.ID & "&key=" & Me.IDHashed
Dim strRequestUrl As String = "<a href=""http://" & strRequestLink & """>http://" & strRequestLink & "</a>"
```

I used the above formatting.